# nodemon is running my script multiple times

Tags: node.js, webpack, nodemon

I have this script in my package.json

```
"watch": "nodemon --watch components --watch helpers --watch redux --watch services --watch types --watch views --watch assets -e ts,scss,css --exec \"npm run build:localhost\"",
```

So my nodemon is watching my local folders, I just save a single file and this many processes are created.

[image]

I use this script to call my webpack build command upon saving a file. This webpack command builds a dist which is the server by a local nginx to localhost.

Is there a way to go over the problem?